# Logic Pro - How do I change from one scale to another (e.g. from G major to E major) in the same track?

Tags: logic-pro

I tried many things but with no luck.
I want to switch to the same track I create from G major to E major.
the only setting I see is the global solution on top.
I want half of my track to be in `G major` and the other half in `E major`.
Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Open the "Signature Track"
Click in the time/beat ruler at the appropriate point
Control-click on the Signature track and select "Create Key Signature"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Actually, I can't find the "Signature Track" you mention. 
I found another property when I was on the score sheet named "Part Box: Customized".  I found everything in there and with the pencil tool you can add it to the score sheet.  And it worked.

Comment: Open the Main Window. At the top, next to the timeline click on the button that shows "Global Tracks". You should now see the Signature track. Alternatively, use the "Open Signature List" command (type that in Help) and add the key signature there.